# Python: 'break' outside loop

Tags: python

in the following python code:

```
narg=len(sys.argv)
print "@length arg= ", narg
if narg == 1:
        print "@Usage: input_filename nelements nintervals"
        break
```

I get:

```
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

Why?

Comment: What do you think `break` does here?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: The optparse module (or similar) will make parsing argv much simpler. http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Because break cannot be used to break out of an if - it can only break out of loops. That's the way Python (and most other languages) are specified to behave.

What are you trying to do? Perhaps you should use `sys.exit()` or `return` instead?

Comment: and how could I do so the scripts stops here?

Comment: `sys.exit()` terminates the program immediately.

Comment: `raise SystemExit` terminates the program; `sys.exit()` raises it, if you prefer a function call.

Comment: I guess `return` was the OP's intention

Answer (score 6):

`break` breaks out of a loop, not an `if` statement, as others have pointed out. The motivation for this isn't too hard to see; think about code like

```
for item in some_iterable:
    ...
    if break_condition():
        break
```

The `break` would be pretty useless if it terminated the `if` block rather than terminated the loop -- terminating a loop conditionally is the exact thing `break` is used for.

Comment: Is your last sentence equivalent to "A break should only be used directly inside a loop."?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl I don't think so. What do you mean "directly"?

Comment: a break in a loop, where this break is not under a condition. the code in your response is a case where break is not "directly" in the loop -- it is inside of a condition. somehow your last sentence was grammatically unclear to me :-)

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl I rephrased -- I was trying to say that you would never put `break` directly inside a loop. You always put it inside an `if` inside a loop.

Answer (score 5):

Because break can only be used inside a loop.
It is used to break out of a loop (stop the loop).

Answer (score 4):

Because the break statement is intended to break out of loops. You don't need to break out of an if statement - it just ends at the end.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but if you wanted to break out of an if statement, you could do:

```
while 1:
    if blah:
        break
```