# Python Syntax Error, 'break' is outside the loop

Tags: python, loops, syntax-error, break

```
try:

    ip = float(input("Enter a number to find it's absolute value (press 'e' to exit):"))
    if ip == 'e':
        break
```

Python is saying that break is outside of the loop. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you having that code? You can't break from an `if` block.

Comment: Do you *have* a loop at all? `if` and `try` are *not* loops.

Comment: Did you look this up [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462566/python-break-outside-loop)?

Comment: They are all in functions

Answer (score 5):

`break` cannot be used outside of loops.

If you are in a function, use `return` instead, or `sys.exit()` if not.

Comment: or `sys.exit()` if neither.

Comment: @kroolik err, might want to try `pass` in this case.

Comment: @Brian yeah, strictly speaking it depends on what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Actually, `sys.exit()` has similar semantics to `break` and `return` - it interrupts current flow, preventing further instructions to be parsed. `pass` wouldn't prevent that.

Comment: Why not just use `raise SystemExit()`?  If you use `sys.exit()`, you have to first import `sys`.

Comment: @iCodez: Or just `raise SystemExit`, with no arguments

Answer (score 1):

`break` can only be used to break out of a for-loop or a while-loop.  If it is used anywhere else, an error will be thrown.

Here is an overview of [`break`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/break.html):

If you want to come out of a function, you need to use `return`.  Or, if you want to exit the program, do this:

```
raise SystemExit
```