# I'm getting this error SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Tags: python

```
for tweet_json in content:
    counter += 1
if counter > tweets: break
tweet = json.loads(tweet_json)
save_tweet_to_db(tweet)
```

I am getting an error 'break outside loop' and im confused

Comment: Your `if` statement itself is outside the loop. By extension, the break is too. Indentation matters!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: 'break' outside loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462566/python-break-outside-loop)

Comment: Indentation is an important thing when writing python.

Answer (score 1):

`break` statement is used to break a loop. Which means it should be always inside loop.

In this case you need to add break inside `for` loop. I think this is the code you were trying.

```
for tweet_json in content:
    counter += 1
    if counter > tweets: 
        break
    tweet = json.loads(tweet_json)
    save_tweet_to_db(tweet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you formatted the code snipped on SO as you have it in your code, you need to fix indentation to correctly put the `break` into the body of the `for loop`.

```
for tweet_json in content:
    counter += 1
    if counter > tweets: 
        break
    tweet = json.loads(tweet_json)
    save_tweet_to_db(tweet)
```

Answer (score 0):

`break`statement only works with loops.

for example:

```py
for i in range(0,101):
    if i == 5:
        break
```

will stop and exit your loop when i reaches the 5 value.

Here your break statement seems to be outside your loop:

```py
for tweet_json in content:
    counter += 1
if counter > tweets: break
```

You need to move it into you loop by changing your code indent:

```py
for tweet_json in content:
    counter += 1
    if counter > tweets: break
```