# 'if' and 'elif' and 'else' in python question

Tags: python, if-statement

My Current Code:

```
age = int(input("Your Age is:"))
if (age <11 or age >60 ):
    print("You are not eligible")
    break

elif (age >=11 and age<=60):
    print("You are eligible")
    continue

elif (age >15 and age<60):
    print('Ticket is $20')

elif (age >=11 and age<=15):
    print("Ticket is $10")
```

Output:

```
File "<ipython-input-12-47ead3cda82a>", line 7
    print("You are eligible to watch a football match")
           ^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

What I want to do:

If the age is less than 11 and or greater than 60 it should display ***You are not eligible*** and break the loop right there.

But if the age is between 11 and 60 then it should display ***You are eligible*** and then next loop starts i.e if age is greater than 15 and less than 60 then it should display ***Ticket is $20*** else age between greater or equal to 11 and less or equal to 15 display ***Ticket is $15***

Comment: This code isn't inside a loop. Loops are created with `for` or `while`.

Comment: I don't think you understand what a "loop" is. `if` is not a loop, a loop is something that repeats.

Comment: Thank you..I have just started writing these conditions so forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: 'break' outside loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462566/python-break-outside-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a loop, you can't use `break` and `continue`. A loop is created with a `for` or `while` statement -- it's a metaphor for something that goes around repeatedly, like a loop of string.

You should use nested `if` statements if you want to refine the criteria.

Also, don't use `elif` when the condition is the exact opposite of the `if` condition. Just use `else:` and leave out the condition.

```
if (age <11 or age >60 ):
    print("You are not eligible")
else:
    print("You are eligible")

    if (15 < age <60):
        print('Ticket is $20')
    else:
        print("Ticket is $10")
```

Comment: But when the age is less than 11 and greater than 60. It still continues with other if else conditions. It should only display You are not eligible...

Comment: It shouldn't. Are you sure you got the indentation right?

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in a loop.
This is an alternate solution. The range is a cooler way of doing things.

Remember `range(a,b)` starts from `a` and goes till `b-1`

This is a solution of a **different flavor**. I have just shown a way.

> I know this does not satisfy all criteria in your question.

I believe you are smart enough to tweak it to make it yours.

```py
while(True):
    # starting an infinite while loop

    age = int(input("Your Age is: "))

    if age in range(15, 60):

        print("Ticket is $20")
        continue

    if age in range(11, 15):

        print("Ticket is $10")
        continue

    print("You are not eligible")
    break
```

The `break` statement terminates the loop containing it. Control of the program flows to the statement immediately after the body of the loop.

If the `break` statement is inside a nested loop (loop inside another loop), the break statement will terminate the innermost loop.

The `continue` statement is used to skip the rest of the code inside a loop for the current iteration only. Loop does not terminate but continues on with the next iteration.

In your example you have used `break` outside a loop.

Comment: Wbat's the point of the loop? The answer to the question isn't going to change when it repeats.

Comment: the author may need a loop. Just a fun project may be

Answer (score 1):

I believe you meant to do this:

```
age = int(input("Your Age is: "))
IsEligible = True
while age!=-1:  # input age as -1 will break the loop
    if age <11 or age >60:
        print("You are not eligible")
        IsEligible = False
    # now for this iteration we know that the age is eligible
    if IsEligible:
        print "you are eligible"
        if age<=15 and age>=11:
            print("Ticket is $15")
        else:
            print "Ticket is $20 "
    age = int(input("Your Age is: "))
    IsEligible = True
```

Comment: What's the point of the loop? The person's age isn't going to change.

Comment: I thought thats a system for typing age and receiving price or/and state, for any number of people he wants

Comment: The code he posted is just for answering about one person. How it gets used as part of the larger application is a separate issue. It could be in a function, and the loop is in the caller.