# How do I stop my code from infinitely printing "Access Denied"?

Tags: python

```
name = input(str("Enter your firstname "))
surname = input(str("Enter your surname "))
username = surname[0:2] + name[0:3]
password = input("Make a password ")
passwordconfirm = input("Enter password again ")
while password != passwordconfirm:
    print("Password is not the same try again ")
    password = input("Make a password ")
    passwordconfirm = input("Enter password again ")
print("This is your username and password:\n" + username + "\n" + password)
attempt = 0
login1 = input("Enter your username ")
login2 = input("Enter your password ")
while True:
    if login1 == username and login2 == password:
        print("Welcome back " + name + " " + surname)
        break
    else:
        print("Access denied")
        attempt += 1
```

#When I run the program and username or password is incorrect it starts to infinitely print "Access Denied"

Comment: break is used in loops not in if else.

Comment: There isn't a loop in the code you posted ... only `while` and `for` are loops. `if` is merely a branch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: 'break' outside loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2462566/2745495)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, I think the code needs a few more steps to make it work. If I understand it well, you want the user to sign up for a new account using username and password. Then, you need to verify it to see if it's correct.

Here is a sample:

```
#*********** BEGIN ACCOUNT CREATION ***************
msg = "Invalid entry. Try again."
print("Welcome to Python Account!")
while True:
    # ***** THIS BLOCK CREATES NEW USERNAME
    try:
        username = input("Create New Username: ") #create new username
    except ValueError:
        msg
    else:
        try:
            username2 = input("Confirm username: ") # confirm username
        except ValueError:
            msg
        else:
            if username2 != username: # if no match, try again
                print("Usernames do not match. Try again.")
                continue
            else:
                print("Username created!")
                
                #THIS BLOCK CREATES NEW PASSWORD
                while True:
                    try:
                        password = input("Create a new password: ")
                    except ValueError:
                        msg
                    else:
                        password2 = input("Confirm password: ")
                        if password2 != password:
                            print("Passwords don't match. Try again.")
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Password created!")
                            break
                    break
    break
# ****************** END ACCOUNT CREATION ******************


# # ****************** BEGIN ACCOUNT LOGIN *****************
print("PLEASE LOG INTO YOUR ACCOUNT")
attempts = 5 # this will allow 5 attempts
while attempts > 0:
    attempts -= 1
    try:
        usrnm = input("Enter username: ")
        pwd = input("Enter password: ")
    except ValueError:
        msg
    else:
        if usrnm.isspace() or pwd.isspace():
            print("Space not allowed.")
            continue
        elif usrnm == '' or pwd == '':
            print("Value needed.")
            continue
        elif usrnm != username2 or pwd != password2:
            print("Credentials do not match. Try again.")
            print(f'You have {attempts} attempts left')

            if attempts == 0: # once user exhausts attempts, account is locked
                print("You have been locked out of your account")
                break
            continue

        else:
            print(f"Welcome {username2}!")
            break
    break
# *************** END ACCOUNT CREATION *************
```

WITHOUT TRY/EXCEPT

```
#*********** BEGIN ACCOUNT CREATION ***************
msg = "Invalid entry. Try again."
print("Welcome to Python Account!")
while True:
    # ***** THIS BLOCK CREATES NEW USERNAME

        username = input("Create New Username: ") #create new username
        username2 = input("Confirm username: ") # confirm username

        if username2 != username: # if no match, try again
            print("Usernames do not match. Try again.")
            continue
        else:
            print("Username created!")
            
            #THIS BLOCK CREATES NEW PASSWORD
            while True:
                password = input("Create a new password: ")
                password2 = input("Confirm password: ")
                if password2 != password:
                    print("Passwords don't match. Try again.")
                    continue
                else:
                    print("Password created!")
                    break
            break
# ****************** END ACCOUNT CREATION ******************


# # ****************** BEGIN ACCOUNT LOGIN *****************
print("PLEASE LOG INTO YOUR ACCOUNT")
attempts = 5 # this will allow 5 attempts
while attempts > 0:
    attempts -= 1
    usrnm = input("Enter username: ")
    pwd = input("Enter password: ")

    if usrnm.isspace() or pwd.isspace():
        print("Space not allowed.")
        continue
    elif usrnm == '' or pwd == '':
        print("Value needed.")
        continue
    elif usrnm != username2 or pwd != password2:
        print("Credentials do not match. Try again.")
        print(f'You have {attempts} attempts left')

        if attempts == 0: # once user exhausts attempts, account is locked
            print("You have been locked out of your account")
            break
        continue

    else:
        print(f"Welcome {username2}!")
        break

# *************** END ACCOUNT CREATION *************
```

Comment: i tried it and it just loops Access denied over and over again

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code, please?

Comment: name = input(str("Enter your firstname "))
surname = input(str("Enter your surname "))
username = surname[0:2] + name[0:3]
password = input("Make a password ")
passwordconfirm = input("Enter password again ")
while password != passwordconfirm:
    print("Password is not the same try again ")
    password = input("Make a password ")
    passwordconfirm = input("Enter password again ")
print("This is your username and password:\n" + username + "\n" + password)
attempt = 0
login1 = input("Enter your username ")
login2 = input("Enter your password ")

Comment: while True:
    if login1 == username and login2 == password:
        print("Welcome back " + name + " " + surname)
        break
    else:
        print("Access denied")
        attempt += 1

Comment: Can you update the question instead, please. This is unformatted and hard to work with

Comment: I updated the question I hope you can understand it better now.

Comment: I updated my answer. See if this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes thankyou that code works, i do have a question though what does valuerror do?

Comment: That's an exception in case the user enters a value that is not allowed. In this particular example is not doing much though. I updated the answer and took out all of the try/except blocks. If you find my answer useful, please upvote and check the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

`break` breaks out of a loop, not an `if`statement or `function` as others have mentioned above. Your program will stop running itself if conditions are matched.

```
if login1 == username and login2 == password:
    print("Welcome back " + name + " " + surname)
else:
    print("Access Denied.")
```

Comment: the problem is that once it is wrong i doesnt allow it to enter anything it just prints infinetly "Access Denied"